# How to constraint InfoPath form page view to certain group of users

Tags: infopath, form, page-view

May I know if it is possible to set a constraint where certain group of users can see certain page view of a web-based InfoPath 2007 form?

Scenario: 
I have 3 group of users - Group A, Group B and Group C 
In my InfoPath form, I have 3 views - View All (which only Group A can view), Issue Loan (which only Group B can view) and Repair (which only Group C can view).
I do not wish to create 3 different form and hope to utilize the page view for InfoPath form in my scenario.

Comment: Are you using InfoPath with SharePoint? If so, what version? There are some very cool things you can do with MOSS 2007 that you cannot do with WSS3.0 using the UserProfileService as well.

Comment: Can tell me more about the UserProfileService. (By the way, your UserprofileService is not the GetUserProfilebyName, correct?)

Comment: The UserProfileService.asmx is a web service, there is a method called GetUserProfileByName which can be used to get a user profile, within that, you can get all of the available properties that show in the profile, including groups. Then you could use a rule that if the groups contains "Group A" then open in View All.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can but it is not simple. I will provide some info to get you started.

Basically you need to find current user groups and then build view conditions according to your needs. This can be done by some coding or by using SharePoint [webservices](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878586%28v=office.12%29.aspx). There is one nice web service called [Users and Groups Web Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772647%28v=office.12%29.aspx) with method called [UserGroup.GetGroupCollectionFromUser Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms772552%28v=office.12%29.aspx). If you provide user login name to it (eg. by using `userName()` function in InfoPath) it will return all users groups.

However there is slight problem and InfoPath doesn't handle web service results as expected. This can be fixed by following steps in this article:

[InfoPath: Displaying SharePoint Group List Using “GetGroupCollectionFromUser” method](http://rawatsumit.blogspot.com/2009/10/infopath-displaying-sharepoint-group.html)

And here you have one great tutorial that almost cover your requirement:

[InfoPath – User Roles in Browser-Enabled Forms Using AD Groups](http://claytoncobb.wordpress.com/2009/07/19/infopath-user-roles-in-browser-enabled-forms-using-groups/)

Comment: I agree that InfoPath can only be used for simple form and not for complex requirements. I will mark your answer as the solution since it looks like there is no other way to do it.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve same task like you but I'm not sure how.. Can you please show how you did this, step by step.. This would be a great help..