# InfoPath - Is it possible to switch default views and then save this setting with a button?

Tags: infopath

So lets say that I have two views, one that is the default and another that can be triggered with a button. Is it possible to switch views, then have the view that you switched to become the default view? So that if the form were opened again it would still be on the view you switched to?

If not, is there a way to have a part of a form read-only to a certain group in SharePoint and editable to another group?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To change Default view you need to change the form template. This is not possible without publishing new form template to SharePoint.

However you have one simple workaround (lets say you have two views: View1 and View2):

1. Add new field to your template and name it `DefaultView`
2. Set its default value to `1`
3. Add button with rule: `Change field A to 2`
4. Add new Form Load rule: `If A = 1 switch to View1`
5. Add second rule to Form Load: `If A = 2 switch to View2`

When form loads it will switch to desired view. You can extend/change this simple example according to your requirements.

For second part of your question you can take a look at my answer provided to this question:

[How to constraint InfoPath form page view to certain group of users](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/19504/how-to-constraint-infopath-form-page-view-to-certain-group-of-users/19512#19512)

Comment: How do you add a form load rule? I am using InfoPath 2007.

Comment: [InfoPath Basics: How to populate an InfoPath form when it is opened/loaded](http://www.bizsupportonline.net/infopath2007/infopath-basics-how-to-populate-form-when-opened-loaded.htm)

Comment: Could you please share some sample codes?
I really appriciate it;